# google sites as my web site in my domain

Tags: dns, google-apps

I bought a domain www.whatever.com and i'm currently using google apps.
Is there a way i can use one of my google sites as my website in my domain?
To explain myself better:
When anyone access my domain www.whatever.com i want people to see my google site i created with google apps.

Thankyou very much for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These links may help:

http://googlesitesblog.blogspot.com/2008/07/google-sites-on-your-domain.html

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99448

I think this question may be more suited to serverfault: https://serverfault.com/

Comment: thankyou shookster you've helped me a lot. it's now working!!

Answer (score 0):

Its called domain fowarding.

You go to your registrar and forward with masking or without masking your domain to the google app site home.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection

http://help.godaddy.com/article/422

Answer (score 0):

I believe the service is called "Google Apps for Your Domain" see [google apps for your domain](http://www.google.com/a/cpanel/domain/new). I hope this helps.